# how to insert the output of php query into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to insert data into my database but the outout is

```
<?php echo ''.pq('#giro_0 td[align="right"]')->html();?>
```

how to get it into

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ing(aaa,bbb,ccc) 
VALUES(CURDATE(),'bbb', XXX )";
```

where the XXX is so i can put the value into my database.

Answer (score 0):

You put it in a variable instead of echoing it.

```
$html = pq('#giro_0 td[align="right"]')->html();
```

Then you stick a placeholder in your SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ing(aaa,bbb,ccc) VALUES(CURDATE(),'bbb', ? )";
```

Then you use whatever function your database API uses to [populate placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $html);
```

Comment: Hello Quentin,
i have made this code :

$html = pq('#giro_0 td[align="right"]')->html();
'
$sql = "INSERT INTO ing(datum,rekening,bedrag) 
VALUES(CURDATE(),'BBB', '?' )";

$stmt = $conn->prepare('update ing set bedrag = ? where id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('si', $html);
$stmt->execute();
'

but now i get this error : ' Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables '

Comment: @spotje — `'?'` is not `?`

Comment: when i do that i get this error :
    Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in E:\Dropbox\-- webserver\dashboard\php\ing.php on line 88
Error: INSERT INTO ing(datum,rekening,bedrag) VALUES(CURDATE(),'BBB', ? )
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? )' at line 2

Comment: Did you prepare the statement first?

Comment: this is my statement  
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('update ing set bedrag = ? where id = ?');     
$stmt->bind_param('s', $html);
$stmt->execute();

Comment: Your original SQL only had one question mark in it. The bind_params statement passes in one parameter. Your new SQL has two question marks in it but your bind_param statement still only has one parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it just inserting the value into the query?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ing(aaa,bbb,ccc) 
VALUES(CURDATE(),'bbb', " . pq('#giro_0 td[align="right"]')->html() . " )";
```

Comment: No. That wouldn't generate valid SQL. Strings have to be quoted. Special characters have to be escaped.

Comment: Use one of PHP's libraries or built-in functions for escaping the string in that case.